# If cell H5 contains X return value from H5, else return value from cell ##

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am stumped on something i thought was very simple to acheive;

If the cell contains a number or better still starts with lets say letter "P", then return the value from that cell, if not return a different argument.

I am trying to override a calculated figure, if a manual figure is entered;
The manual figure will ALWAYS take precedent over the calculated figure.

I have tried the following scenarios, all of which do not work entirely;

```
=IF(LEFT(H5,1) = "£", H5, SUM(AO5:AU5))
```

I appreciate that it is only looking for the £ sign, i have tried various combinations

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(,H7,1)),H7,SUM(AO7:AU7))
```

This works, but returns anything entered in cell H7 not just if it contains a number

```
=IF(H8>=1,H8,SUM(AO8:AU8))
```

This works, but returns anything entered in cell H8 not just if it contains a number

Again i appreciate why they return anything, i just don't know how to write the argument correctly.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you want to search left 1 for `£` then return something, else other thing? Or do you want to search a cell for numbers only and then return something, else other thing? Can you put some sample data?

Comment: Apologies for the late response i have been away and thank you for your responses.

Ok in lets say cell M5 which is protected etc, i have a formula that displays a calculated cost, if the user enters any numeric value in cell H5 i want this to be displayed in cell M5, if they enter anything other than a numeric value then i want cell M5 to ignore it.

I'm happy for the argument to include a £ if that is easier so that if cell H5 starts with a £ then use H5 else use the original calculating for formula.

I hope this makes sense

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure what the exact problem is, but building on your formulas, here are some tests and their results:

[image: Formulas]

Seems to me that all formulas work as expected. If this is not the case for you, you have to describe (1) the expected result and (2) what result you are actually getting.

Comment: Apologies for the late response i have been away and thank you for your responses. Ok in lets say cell M5 which is protected etc, i have a formula that displays a calculated cost, if the user enters any numeric value in cell H5 i want this to be displayed in cell M5, if they enter anything other than a numeric value then i want cell M5 to ignore it. I'm happy for the argument to include a £ if that is easier so that if cell H5 starts with a £ then use H5 else use the original calculating for formula. I hope this makes sense Many thanks

Comment: The formulas I used above lets you use both of those options. Are they not working for you?

Comment: Hi Vegard, Apologies, yes the =IF(ISNUMBER... worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: If your issue has been resolved, please use the checkmark next to my answer to indicate that it solved your question. :)